# XSL - Make a for-each inside a node

Tags: xml, foreach, xslt-1.0

I posted like three weeks ago a question about XSL 1.0 that received a great answer about for-each. But now I need some advice about making a for-each inside a node. I'm pretty sure this is a noob question, but please help me away.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <eOrden xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <EquipoServicio>
      <eElemento>
        <Clave>PAMO1</Clave> 
        <Descripcion>MODEM</Descripcion> 
      </eElemento>
      <eElemento>
        <Clave>ISP01</Clave> 
        <Descripcion>PRODIGY</Descripcion> 
      </eElemento>
      <eElemento>
        <Clave>IFR28</Clave> 
        <Descripcion>ACCESS</Descripcion> 
      </eElemento>
    </EquipoServicio>
  </eOrden>
```

My XSL (so far):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/eOrden">

    <html>
        <head></head>
          <body>
            <div>
                <section class="sections">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="lbold">EQUIPO O SERVICIO</legend>

                        <div class="primerdiv" style="width:99.5%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 7px; ">

                            <xsl:for-each select="EquipoServicio/eElemento[position() mod 7 = 1]" >
                                <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:12.3%;">
                                    <div class="primerdiv letra" style="padding-top:2px; padding-bottom: 2px; width:100%">
                                        <div class="primerdiv eqsertitulo lbold" style="text-align:right; width:100%">
                                            EQ. O SERV.:&#xA0;
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="primerdiv eqsertitulo lbold" style="text-align:right; width:100%">
                                            DESCR.:&#xA0;
                                         </div>
                                      </div>
                                   </div>

                                <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::EquipoServicio/eElemento[position() &lt; 7]"/>

                            </xsl:for-each>

                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </section>
            </div>
          </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="eElemento">
    <div class="altbordeptes" style="float:left; width:12%;">
        <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:98.5%;">
            <div class="eqser letra" style="border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; text-align:left; width:98.5%;">
                <xsl:value-of select="Clave"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:98.5%;">
            <div class="eqser letra" style="border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; text-align:left; width:99.5%;">
                <xsl:value-of select="Descripcion"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why, if I run this, the iteration just gets the the info on the first `eElemento` node and not the whole three nodes? If I take the `eElemento` nodes outside the `EquipoServicio` node the output is correct!!

The result I expect is like this:

```
<section class="sections">
         <fieldset>
            <legend class="lbold">EQUIPO O SERVICIO</legend>
            <div class="primerdiv" style="width:99.5%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 7px; ">
               <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:12.3%;">
                  <div class="primerdiv letra" style="padding-top:2px; padding-bottom: 2px; width:100%">
                     <div class="primerdiv eqsertitulo lbold" style="text-align:right; width:100%">
                                                            EQ. O SERV.:&nbsp;

                     </div>
                     <div class="primerdiv eqsertitulo lbold" style="text-align:right; width:100%">
                                                               DESCR.:&nbsp;

                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="altbordeptes" style="float:left; width:12%;">
                  <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:98.5%;">
                     <div class="eqser letra" style="border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; text-align:left; width:100%;">PAMO1</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:98.5%;">
                     <div class="eqser letra" style="border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; text-align:left; width:100%;">MODEM</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="altbordeptes" style="float:left; width:12%;">
                  <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:98.5%;">
                     <div class="eqser letra" style="border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; text-align:left; width:100%;">ISP01</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:98.5%;">
                     <div class="eqser letra" style="border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; text-align:left; width:100%;">PRODIGY</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="altbordeptes" style="float:left; width:12%;">
                  <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:98.5%;">
                     <div class="eqser letra" style="border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; text-align:left; width:100%;">IFR28</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="primerdiv letra" style="width:98.5%;">
                     <div class="eqser letra" style="border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; text-align:left; width:100%;">ACCESS</div>
                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
         </fieldset>
      </section>
```

Thanks in advance.
Tonio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::EquipoServicio/eElemento[position() &lt; 7]"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::eElemento[position() &lt; 7]"/>
```

These two are not nearly the same.

---

**Note**:

Your input is not valid: the `EquipoServicio` element has no closing tag. It would also be better to remove all the "noise" (e.g CSS)  that's unessential to the question.